# Homeomorphism of a difference

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have $A\approx B(0,2)$ and $B\approx B(0,1)$, with $B(0,r)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid \lVert x\rVert<r\}$. If $A\backslash B\neq \emptyset$, is $A\backslash B$ homeomorphic to $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid 1\leq\lVert x\rVert<2\}$?

NOTE: $\approx$ means homeomorphic.

Comment: It's not just homeomorphic, *it's the exact same thing*. (And there's no 'if' here, $A \setminus B$ is nonempty.)

Comment: @MikeMiller I think you are wrong in $A\backslash B$ nonempty, because $A\simeq  B(0,1)$ and $A\simeq B(0,2)$, however $A\backslash A$ is empty. But thanks for the answer

Comment: I think there's some confusion with what you mean by "$A \simeq B(0,2)$"

Comment: @MikeMiller My bad. I meant $\approx$

Comment: In that case, no. There's no reason to expect differences should respect *anything* like homeomorphism. You could take $B$ to be the bottom hemisphere of $A$; then $A\setminus B$ is just homeomorphic to the upper half-disc (and definitely not the annulus above). You could pick it so that it separates $A$ into two halves, and so on.